# Apache Zeppelin prefix not found

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am following the instructions from https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0-SNAPSHOT/interpreter/jdbc.html#create-a-new-jdbc-interpreter

When I try to add a new interpreter following the above instructions, I get 'Prefix not found' error. I also binded the interpreter as shown in the link. One thing I noticed though, when I create an interpreter named mysql and selected jdbc from the interpreter group, the interpreter is showing up as mysql %jdbc in the bind options whereas in the link referred above the screenshot is showing as mysql %mysql. Why is there a difference?